# Text Analysis using custom keywords in R

Tags: r, corpus, text-analysis

I am trying to vectorize my text data using R's tm package.

Right now my data corpus is in the following form:

```
1. The sports team practiced today
2. The soccer team went took the day off
```

then the data would get vectorized into:

```
<the, sports, team, practiced, today, soccer, went, took, off>
1.  <1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0>
2.  <1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1>
```

I would prefer to use a group of custom phrases for my vector, such as:

```
<sports team, soccer team, practiced today, day off>
1. <1, 0, 1, 0>
2. <0, 1, 0, 1>
```

Is there a package or function in R that will do this? Or are there any other open-source resources that have similar functionality? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You asked about other text packages, I welcome you to try [`quanteda`](http://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda), which I developed with Paul Nulty.

In the code below, first you define the multi-word phrases you want, as a named list that is typed as a quanteda "dictionary" class object using the `dictionary()` constructor, and then you use `phrasetotoken()` to convert the phrases found in your texts into single "tokens" consisting of the phrasal words concatenated by underscores.  The tokeniser ignored underscores so your phrases are then treated as if they were single-word tokens.

`dfm()` is the constructor for document-feature matrices, can take a regular expressions that define the features to keep, here any phrase containing an underscore character (the regex could of course be refined but I've kept it deliberately simple here).  `dfm()` has a lot of options -- see `?dfm`.

```
install.packages("quanteda")
library(quanteda)

mytext <- c("The sports team practiced today",
            "The soccer team went took the day off")
myphrases <- dictionary(list(myphrases=c("sports team", "soccer team", "practiced today", "day off")))
mytext2 <- phrasetotoken(mytext, myphrases)
mytext2
## [1] "The sports_team practiced_today"       "The soccer_team went took the day_off"
# keptFeatures is a regular expression: keep only phrases

mydfm <- dfm(mytext2, keptFeatures = "_", verbose=FALSE)
mydfm
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 4 features.
## 2 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
## features
## docs    day_off practiced_today soccer_team sports_team
## text1         0               1           0           1
## text2         1               0           1           0
```

Happy to help with any `quanteda`-related questions, including feature requests if you can suggest improvements on phrase handling.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
library(tm)

text <- c("The sports team practiced today", "The soccer team went took the day off")

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))

tokenizing.phrases <- c("sports team", "soccer team", "practiced today", "day off")  

phraseTokenizer <- function(x) {
  require(stringr)

  x <- as.character(x) # extract the plain text from the tm TextDocument object
  x <- str_trim(x)
  if (is.na(x)) return("")
  phrase.hits <- str_detect(x, ignore.case(tokenizing.phrases))

  if (any(phrase.hits)) {
    # only split once on the first hit, so we don't have to worry about multiple occurences of the same phrase
    split.phrase <- tokenizing.phrases[which(phrase.hits)[1]] 
    # warning(paste("split phrase:", split.phrase))
    temp <- unlist(str_split(x, ignore.case(split.phrase), 2))
    out <- c(phraseTokenizer(temp[1]), split.phrase, phraseTokenizer(temp[2])) # this is recursive, since f() calls itself
  } else {
    out <- MC_tokenizer(x)
  }

  # get rid of any extraneous empty strings, which can happen if a phrase occurs just before a punctuation
  out[out != ""]
}


tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tokenize = phraseTokenizer))

> Terms(tdm)
[1] "day off"         "practiced today" "soccer team"     "sports team"     "the"             "took"           
[7] "went"
```

Comment: When I get to the step.....tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs, control = list(tokenize = phraseTokenizer))... I get the following error code....Error in check_pattern(pattern, string) : 
  Lengths of string and pattern not compatible
In addition: Warning message:
In if (is.na(x)) return("") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Ran fine for me.  I tried the call without the control argument and it was fine.  > tdm2 <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
> Terms(tdm2)
 [1] "day"       "off"       "practiced" "soccer"    "sports"    "team"      "the"       "today"     "took"     
[10] "went"